# Newsletter with media query

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a newsletter template. As far as I know only inline CSS will work, so the client could ignore the whole `<head>` tag. Something that I don't understand is how could I create a newsletter with responsive design if I can't even use media queries??

So how could I hide the button in this example?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Newsletter</title>
  <style>
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    button {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ipsam illum doloremque laudantium in error deserunt, molestias impedit ab. Vero nam in itaque soluta, accusamus repellat maxime veritatis minima. Ea! <br>
  <button>Click here</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren’t restricted to just using inline tags. You can also use `<style>` while still only using HTML. This will allow you to use media queries.

Comment: What client are you talking about? Sounds crazy. Maybe using a style tag in body could work...

Comment: Would you mind giving us what you have done so far or any code you attempted to use?

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises I have no codes yet. I was just wondering how it works but I have edited my question and added an example.

Comment: If you want a full cross mail client solution you won't be able to use external CSS. One way to hide a button on a narrow screen could be to set a fixed height + overflow hidden on a parent, and then allow the button to wrap, and when it does it simply disappear outside its parent.